# sed command to replace multiple lines after interval

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I would like to replace the first character `C` with `H` for 23 lines (say, lines 83 to 106) after every interval of 82 lines. How can I do this using `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: awk allows you to select line numbers based on a formula, e.g. the pattern `NR%82>0 && NR%82<=23` selects your lines (there might be a need for fine-tuning the formula). To replace the first C, the `sub` function should be appropriate. I don't know if `sed` has that much flexibility for line selection.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input with associate desired output? It sometimes helps to understand border cases. Also, please indicate what you already tried and where you ran into problems.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a sample file

```
lines_per_set=82
         sets=3
lines=$(( $lines_per_set * $sets ))
  yes CC | head -n "$lines" |  nl > file
```

---

Initialize two counters and downcount them. The outer counter reset triggers re initialisation.

```
awk '
  !k       {j= 24; k= 82}
  j && j-- {sub(/C/,"H")}
  k--
' file
```

---

Same idea as above in GNU sed where the counters are held in the hold space.

```
sed -En '
  G
  /^[^\n]*\n{1,24}$/s/C/H/
  P
  /\n{82}/{z;x;d;}
  z;H
' file
```